# PySpark - converting sas macro with scan function to pyspark

Tags: python, pandas, database, pyspark, sas

I am a beginner in pyspark and python, and trying to convert one of my SAS macro to pyspark, but unable to find useful resources which are equivalent to SCAN function in SAS and also having difficulties when executing while loop in EMR studio pyspark cluster. I am trying to convert the following SAS macro to pyspark, thank you all.

```
-- start macro --

%let a=1;
%do %while (%scan(&varlist., &a.) ne );
    %let d = %scan(&varlist., &a.);
    %put &d. ;

-- end macro --

## &varlist variable contains the values similar to the following list
    [Decimal('124.00000'), Decimal('416.000000'), Decimal('205.00000'), Decimal('332.000000')]
```

Comment: `&i` is not defined in your macro. It's difficult to identify exactly what it is doing without the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the equivalent Python code:

```
for d in [124.0, 416.0, 205.0, 332.0]:
    print(d)
```